# How can I prevent writing 0 instead of non-entered array elements?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I have an assignment, and what we asked for is exactly: The user will enter a number between 0 and 999.999. The steps of this number will be assigned to an array and the array will be printed on the screen. Then repeating numbers in this array will be found and printed on the screen. Here is my source code. My problem is that when the user enters a non-6-digit number, for example, when a 4-digit number is entered, the last 2 elements of the array are automatically 0. As you see below, output says "0 is repeated 2 times". How can I prevent these 0s from being created? [image]

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Windows.h"

int array[6];

void startup()
{
    printf("\t\t\t\t-----------------------------------------\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t|                   |\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t|    Program is starting...         |\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t|                   |\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t-----------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Program is starting. ");
    printf("3..");
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("2..");
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("1");
    Sleep(1000);
    system("cls");
}

void getnumber()
{
    int number, j = 0;

    printf("Enter a number between 0 and 999999: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);

    if (number >= 0 && number <= 999999)
    {
        for (int i = 10; j <= 5; j++)
        {
            array[j] = (number % i);
            number = number / i;
            if (number == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("\n");

        for (j; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            printf("%d ", array[j]);
        }

        printf("\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter a number in the specified range.\n\n");

        printf("\t\t\t\t-----------------------------------------\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t|                   |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t|         Going back....            |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t|                   |\n");
        printf("\t\t\t\t-----------------------------------------\n");

        printf("Going back. ");
        printf("3..");
        Sleep(1000);
        printf("2..");
        Sleep(1000);
        printf("1");
        Sleep(1000);
        system("cls");

        getnumber();
    }
}

void repeateddigit()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        int repeated = 1;

        for (int j = (i + 1); j <= 5; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] == array[j])
            {
                repeated++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d is repeated %d times.\n", array[i], repeated);
        while (array[i] == array[i + 1])
        {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    startup();
    getnumber();
    repeateddigit();

    printf("\n");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I see `int array[6];` my thoughts are immediately; 1) why a global variable. And 2) Why a C-style array and not a `std::array` (or `std::vector`)?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: The problem is that your `repeateddigit` routine assumes that you have six digits. But you know how many digits you actually have in the `getnumber` routine. So the chalenge is how to get that information from `getnumber` to `repeateddigit`.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please tag only the one you are really coding in as answers can be very different depending on the actual language.

Answer (score 1):

You could just safe `j` in `getnumber()` before you decrement it, and then return it to use it in `repeateddigit()` like so:

```
repeateddigit(int from) {
    for(int i = from; ...
    ...
```